# split a string by separator in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of the format

```
s = "a, b, [c, d, ....]"
```

how can I split it into an array with

```
[c, d,, ..]
```

into one element and a and b as another elements of the resultant array cleanly. If I try to use

```
s.split(',')
```

even [c,d, ...] gets split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on 2.6+, then `ast.literal_eval` is the way to go... (assuming you have literals that is - otherwise, maybe use `eval` with caution) - or, look at the `pyparsing` library which has a "safe" eval example at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples (look for parsePythonValue.py)

literal_eval solution:

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = "'a', 'b', ['c', 'd', 'z']"
print literal_eval(s)
```

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` can do it.

```
>>> s = "'a', 'b', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']"
>>> a = eval(s)
>>> a
('a', 'b', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

or you can do a series of modifications to the string.

```
>>> s = "a, b, [c, d, e, f]"
>>> a = s.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(" ","").split(",")
>>> a
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for exchanging data between two systems, you can use json:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '[1, 2, [3, 4]]'
>>> json.loads(s)
[1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

if you need literals, you must quote them.

Answer (score -1):

If you plan on taking a string manipulation approach:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

```
import re

text = "a, b, [c, d, ....]"
matches = re.split(r"\W+", text);
print matches
```

Otherwise I'd use the evaluation methods directly.